# Launched gradle with a test with the --no-daemon parameter but the daemon is launched anyway

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to debug some unit tests I've written but the gradle daemon seems to always launch, ignoring any options I've set.

Using Mac OS X 10.9.5, Java 1.7, Gradle 2.2.1 and robolectric-gradle-plugin 0.14.1

Launching gradle with:

```
GRADLE_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5006"    
./gradlew test --no-daemon -Dorg.gradle.debug=true
```

causes the following line to appear

```
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguid....
```

I've also tried setting the -Xdebug and Xrunjdwp as jvmArgs in build.gradle.

Nothing else happens but if I add -d and rerun, it turns out that the daemon has launched and is waiting on port 5005 for a debugger: http://pastebin.com/TqaXubmr

Finally, if I then launch a debugger attaching to port 5005 the tests run but none of the breakpoints are hit.

The gradle.properties is empty, I haven't set org.gradle.jvmargs.

Answer (score 3):

You might have configure memory settings in your gradle.properties? these can force gradle to launch a new jvm as these settings cannot be applied dynamically.

Keep in mind that unit tests are always executed in a separate jvm. The easiest way to debug tests executed by gradle is to run

```
>gradle :test --debug-jvm
```

this will automatically configure your test task to run with debug enabled.

Comment: I'm trying to attach a debugger to the test process. --debug just turns on debug logging for gradle.

Comment: sorry, I mixed up something here. it is --debug-jvm instead of --debug. updated my answer. sorry for confusing.

Comment: In my case I had "org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M" in "~/.gradle/gradle.properties" (notice home directory). Deleting it prevented gradle from forking jvm.